# Cloning an Azure repo in Azure Runbooks

Tags: powershell, git-clone, azure-automation, posh-git

As a part of this automation thing I am doing, I am required to clone a repo as it has a json file that I will need to use for automation. I have imported `posh-git` but I am unable to run `git clone <url>` in it. Here is the error: `git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Obviously, I have added my account in the Source Control. So, I have done 
`$SourceControl = Get-AzureRmAutomationSourceControl -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -Name testRepo -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName`

And then I am doing `git clone $SourceControl.RepoUrl`

And it fails with said error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not define a json object directly in the runbook?

Comment: I'm sorry. Its not a json file, it's a ps1 script. My bad. So it becomes all the more ethical to clone it, I suppose?

Comment: The `git clone` will obtain a Git repository on your local machine, but in the runbook, I don't think you can do that. Why not copy the script in the ps1 directly  to the runbook?

Comment: I can do this: `git clone $SourceControl.RepoUrl "$env:TEMP"` which is actually the part of my code, just that I hadn't put that in.

Comment: And then go into that directory to fetch that file.. No?

Comment: Does your repo locate in the github?

Comment: No. It's on an Azure DevOps repo. It clones fine on PowerShell locally, but not on Azure Runbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not use the `posh-git` module in the runbook, becasue there is no git installed in the runbook, so you will get the error.

See the option 3 in the [Prerequisites](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#prerequisites):

> Git must be installed and available via the PATH environment variable. Check that git is accessible from PowerShell by executing git --version from PowerShell. **If git is not recognized as the name of a command, verify that you have Git installed.** If not, install Git from https://git-scm.com. If you have Git installed, make sure the path to git is in your PATH environment variable.

Your option is to  write all your script in the repository, configure the source control and sync the job, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/source-control-integration#syncing).

Or if you just want to get the .ps1 file, you could store it as a blob in the storage account, then use the [`Get-AzStorageBlobContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-3.5.0) to get it.

Comment: Thanks. I need some time to try something. Let me get back to you. I'll mark this as the Answer if nothing works.

Comment: Hey, sorry. What I tried didn't work. So I've marked your response as the answer.